# Making a for loop with dplyr, group_by, summarize, and saving the output of each variable in a list

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyeval

I want to make a function saving the output in a list. My concern is how to specify which column with dplyr group_by and summaries. Imagine a big dataset. See further comments below.

```
trt <- rep(LETTERS[1:3],3)
qw <- sample(100,9)
tr <- sample(100,9)
df <- data.frame(trt,qw,tr)


  df %>%
  group_by(trt) %>%
  summarise(mean.mpg = mean(qw, na.rm = TRUE),
            sd.mpg = sd(qw, na.rm = TRUE),
            n.mpg = n())%>%
  mutate(se.mpg = sd.mpg / sqrt(n.mpg),
         lower.ci.mpg = mean.mpg - qt(1 - (0.05 / 2), n.mpg - 1) * se.mpg,
         upper.ci.mpg = mean.mpg + qt(1 - (0.05 / 2), n.mpg - 1) * se.mpg)
```

Why does n[i] not work? How should this be specified to be able to use it in a function?

```
n <- colnames(df)[2:3]
   

df %>%
   group_by(trt) %>%
   summarise(mean.mpg = mean(n[i], na.rm = TRUE),   
             sd.mpg = sd(n[i], na.rm = TRUE),
             n.mpg = n())%>%
   mutate(se.mpg = sd.mpg / sqrt(n.mpg),
          lower.ci.mpg = mean.mpg - qt(1 - (0.05 / 2), n.mpg - 1) * se.mpg,
          upper.ci.mpg = mean.mpg + qt(1 - (0.05 / 2), n.mpg - 1) * se.mpg)
```

In the end I want to make this loop and save the output in a list

```
list_Data <- list()

for (i in 2:ncol(df)){
  list_Data[[i]]<- df %>%
    group_by(trt) %>%
    summarise(mean.mpg = mean(n[i], na.rm = TRUE),
              sd.mpg = sd(n[i], na.rm = TRUE),
              n.mpg = n())%>%
    mutate(se.mpg = sd.mpg / sqrt(n.mpg),
           lower.ci.mpg = mean.mpg - qt(1 - (0.05 / 2), n.mpg - 1) * se.mpg,
           upper.ci.mpg = mean.mpg + qt(1 - (0.05 / 2), n.mpg - 1) * se.mpg)
}
```

Wanted output:

```
  [[1]]
    # A tibble: 3 x 7
      trt   mean.mpg sd.mpg n.mpg se.mpg lower.ci.mpg upper.ci.mpg
      <chr>    <dbl>  <dbl> <int>  <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
    1 A         35.7   32.9     3   19.0        -46.0         117.
    2 B         46     37.2     3   21.5        -46.5         139.
    3 C         64.3   47.8     3   27.6        -54.4         183.


[[2]]
# A tibble: 3 x 7
  trt   mean.mpg sd.mpg n.mpg se.mpg lower.ci.mpg upper.ci.mpg
  <chr>    <dbl>  <dbl> <int>  <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
1 A         57.7   40.5     3   23.4        -42.8         158.
2 B         49.3   31.0     3   17.9        -27.7         126.
3 C         32.7   34.8     3   20.1        -53.8         119.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to index the `.data` pronoun, which can be done when column names are stored as strings:

```
for (i in 1:length(n)){        # <-- Note the change from 2:ncol(df)
  list_Data[[i]]<- df %>%
    group_by(trt) %>%
    summarise(mean.mpg = mean(.data[[n[i]]], na.rm = TRUE),   # <-- .data pronoun here
              sd.mpg = sd(.data[[n[i]]], na.rm = TRUE),       #       and here
              n.mpg = n())%>%
    mutate(se.mpg = sd.mpg / sqrt(n.mpg),
           lower.ci.mpg = mean.mpg - qt(1 - (0.05 / 2), n.mpg - 1) * se.mpg,
           upper.ci.mpg = mean.mpg + qt(1 - (0.05 / 2), n.mpg - 1) * se.mpg)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `sym` function from `rlang` package and then unquote it with `!!` called bang bang operator. Here because you are providing a string as column name you need to first turn it into a symbol which is in fact pointing to an object in your data set and then you have to tell R to evaluate it in the context of your data set by means of forcing evaluation with `!!` operator. You can find out the basics of programming with tidyverse [here](https://tidyeval.tidyverse.org/introduction.html).

```
library(rlang)

n <- colnames(df)[2:3]
list_Data <- vector("list", length = ncol(df) - 1)

for (i in 1:(ncol(df)-1)){
  list_Data[[i]] <- df %>%
    group_by(trt) %>%
    summarise(mean.mpg = mean(!!sym(n[i]), na.rm = TRUE),
              sd.mpg = sd(!!sym(n[i]), na.rm = TRUE),
              n.mpg = n()) %>%
    mutate(se.mpg = sd.mpg / sqrt(n.mpg),
           lower.ci.mpg = mean.mpg - qt(1 - (0.05 / 2), n.mpg - 1) * se.mpg,
           upper.ci.mpg = mean.mpg + qt(1 - (0.05 / 2), n.mpg - 1) * se.mpg)
}


> list_Data
[[1]]
# A tibble: 3 x 7
  trt   mean.mpg sd.mpg n.mpg se.mpg lower.ci.mpg upper.ci.mpg
  <chr>    <dbl>  <dbl> <int>  <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
1 A         62.7   30.6     3  17.7        -13.4         139. 
2 B         36.7   14.0     3   8.09         1.86         71.5
3 C         17.7   16.5     3   9.53       -23.3          58.7

[[2]]
# A tibble: 3 x 7
  trt   mean.mpg sd.mpg n.mpg se.mpg lower.ci.mpg upper.ci.mpg
  <chr>    <dbl>  <dbl> <int>  <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
1 A           49   38.0     3   21.9        -45.4        143. 
2 B           36   21.7     3   12.5        -17.8         89.8
3 C           30   26.9     3   15.5        -36.8         96.8
```